# jQuery form resubmission not sending new values

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html, forms

I have a form that allows one to test an app by mimicking the JSON data coming from another app. The idea is that the user edits the form, hits submit, receives a sample response from the server, and then is allowed to edit the form and submit again. The form is submitted by jQuery AJAX. I'm using a serializing function to gather the data and turn it into a string.

Submitting the form works the first time, but each subsequent submission sends the same data, unless the page is refreshed. I believe the problem is that jQuery is building the form object based on `$( '#graphForm ')` only once, and is not updating the field values upon second submission. Or, I'm not getting the values in my `$.serializeFormJSON()` UDF, in a way that gets updated values.

```
//Grab the form data, parse values and stringify
(function ($) {

    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {
        var data = {}, form = this.serializeArray();

        $.each( form, function () {
            //correct the value formats and variable typing
            if ( this.value.match( /^\-?\d+$/ ) ) {
                this.value = parseInt( this.value );
            } else if ( this.value.match( /^\-?\d+\.\d+$/ ) ) {
                this.value = parseFloat( this.value );
            } else if ( this.value == "null" ) {
                this.value = null;
            }
            //fill the data object
            if ( data[this.name]) {
                if ( !data[this.name].push) {
                    data[this.name] = [data[this.name]];
                }
                data[this.name].push(this.value);
            } else {
                data[this.name] = this.value;
            }
        });
        return JSON.stringify( data );
    };

})(jQuery);

$( document ).ready(function(){
    //grab form data from last session
    if ( oldFormDataCookie = Cookies.get( "formData" ) ) {
        oldFormData = JSON.parse( oldFormDataCookie );
        $.each(oldFormData, function( name, value ) {
            $( '*[name="' + name + '"]' ).val( value );
            console.log('*[name="' + name + '"] : ' + value);
        });
    }
    $( "#closeOverlay, #overlay, #overlayContent" ).click( function() {
        $( "#overlay" ).fadeOut();
    });

    //Serialize values, submit form, show the sample, save values
    $( "#graphForm" ).submit( function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $( this ).serializeFormJSON();
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: $( "#graphForm" ).attr( 'action' ),
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( response ) {
                    Cookies.set("formData", formData );
                    console.log( response );
                    $( "#overlayContent" ).html( '<img src="' + response.url + '">' );
                    $( "#overlay" ).fadeIn();
                }
            }
        );    
    });
});
```

Comment: lol `if ( oldFormDataCookie = Cookies.get( "formData" ) )`

Comment: that only happens when the pages is loaded. i almost had a facepalm when i read your comment lol

Comment: I remember reading someplace that .val() returns original value and .attr() returns updated value.  Not sure though if this is the issue.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. thanks

Comment: Gives me the same issue with `$.attr()`. I think it is of note that I cannot reproduce the problem by performing the `serializeFormJSON()` function in the console. It *only* seems to happen after a form submission.

Comment: @AllenKing other way around

Comment: I remember having a similar issue when the script code was on the same cshtml that was being popuped from another page upon a click.  That cshtml had a form and the text boxes would internally retain the first value even after page refresh (on server side it was always the first entered value being received).  The issue was fixed after the script was moved from the cshtml file to a separate js file.